# ISNA: Return "YES", "NO" in nested formula

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to get it to return YES/NO instead of the the lookup value/#N/A by using ISNA, but I'm not sure where to place it.

Here is my formula:

```
=IF(AND([@Center]="London",[@Reportable]="YES"),VLOOKUP([@ID],Client!C:C,1,FALSE),"IGNORE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `MATCH` as you only want to know if it's in the list.  This will return its location in the list or `#N/A` (`VLOOKUP` may return something that's not a number).

You can then check if it's numeric and return Yes / No as required:

```
=IF(AND([@Center]="London",[@Reportable]="YES"),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@ID],Client!C:C,0)),"Yes","No"),"IGNORE")
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
=IF(AND([@Center]="London",[@Reportable]="YES"),ISNA(VLOOKUP([@ID],Client!C:C,1,FALSE)),"IGNORE")
```

You have to wrap with `ISNA` the desired part of the formula to be affected.

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Nevetheless, this will output TRUE/FALSE, not YES/NO.

Hope it helps.